# Load large amount of data in kendo grid filter options

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have kendo grid using angularjs. I have 40K+ records.

I have set serverFiltering true and when I am clicking on column filter it is calling API that returns 40K+ records which takes long time to display records. I have used server paging also and showing 20 records per page.

Please provide any solution. Is Virtual scrolling possible for filter data?

Comment: As you are using `server-side filtering` in the screen, use `server-side pagination` also. This way it will load only a limited number of records (For example: if pagination is set to 250, it will load only first 250 records quickly rather than loading whole 40k+ records).

Comment: I am showing 20 records per page. I am having issue with 40k filter options . API call returning 40k records

Comment: If you use `server-side pagination`, it will return only 20 records. If it is returning 40k+ records for `server-side pagination` also means something wrong with your backend code for pagination. Check `PageDTO` what values are coming at the server level.

Comment: You need to manage the data in the back-end. You have to return only the desired row amount. What kendo does when set to server paging is to send current pagination information to the API, like current page number and the page size. So your API must filter that by itself and return the related rows, not the whole data. API only sends the whole data when the pagination is made in the client, in that case, the grid manages the pages by itself.